# Unit test a class without interface using MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I am new to MOQ Testing. I have many classes without an interface or abstract method.
one of them also uses some System Interop libraries.
they also have few private members in them which are accessed in the methods.

I want to Unit test these classes (not having interfaces).

I came across these two alternatives:

1. **Private Accessor**
2. **PrivateObject**

but will they provide all unit test funcionality I could have got with having Interfaces?

Comment: The short answer is no, you won't get all the functionality out of your unit tests that you would if you used interfaces. You'll need a lot more boiler plate code and convoluted constructs to try to get this working. If you are able to, I'd highly suggest refactoring your code base to include interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft deprecated private accessors a long time ago. The private accessor generator was flawed and could crash Visual Studio or refuse to build if you used some language constructs that was not properly supported by the accessor generator.

Testing private methods is also a terrible idea in the first place. You want to test a class from the outside such that whatever you throw at the class will make it produce expected results. How the class does what you want it to do is implementation details. If you start writing unit tests for private methods you are creating a dependency that may make it harder to change the implementation details. This defeats one of the purposes of private methods which is to allow the class to change the internals at will as long as the external behavior is unchanged.

My advice is to avoid private tests and instead refactor your classes to make the public methods more testable. Typically this involves an exercise where you split monster classes with monster methods into a fine grained class design with simple classes with simple interfaces.

There is a great book on this topic: "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers. He defines legacy code as code that are not well covered with tests, which I believe matches your code, and describes many concrete techniques to make code more testable.

Moq is a test tool that makes sense if your class dependencies are through interfaces or abstract classes. Here moq can be used to test that your class interacts with some interface in an expected way. The good thing about using moq rather than a concrete implementation is that you concentrate your test on one class and eliminate unexpected side effects in dependent classes and in many cases simplify the test setup.
That means Moq is great for testing how a class interacts with other classes, which is often the most interesting thing to test.

Comment: While "Private Accessors" might not be supported (and I am in no way endorsing testing *private* methods), what about testing *internal* methods? I find these useful to test - knowing that testing internal methods is only part of testing the interface-exposed *public* methods. (It is precisely the re-factoring suggested that leads to many small *internal* methods that can be well-tested.)